# LaTeX acro package: output broken for list style LOF

Tags: acro

I'm using the acro (NOT acronym) package (v2.5) for a list of symbols.
Now, if the short form is rather long it is 'shifted' into the corresponding long form when using `\printacronyms`. Further, if the acronym appears on several pages, the corresponding page numbers will be written over the page instead of using a linebreak.

The following code snippet illustrates this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{forloop}

\DeclareAcronym{MyPI}{
  short = \ensuremath{\pi \in \mathbb{R}},
  alt = \ensuremath{\pi},
  long = Strange number,
  class = nomencl
}
\newcommand{\MyPI}{\aca{MyPI}}

\DeclareAcronym{MySetOfPoints}{
  short = \ensuremath{{\cal{P}} = \{\boldsymbol{x}\}, \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3},
  alt = \ensuremath{{\cal{P}}},
  long = A simple set of points,
  class = nomencl
}
\newcommand{\MySetOfPoints}{\aca{MySetOfPoints}}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 20}%
{%
  \newpage
  $\MyPI_1$
  \newpage
  $\MySetOfPoints$
}

\newpage
\acsetup{
  hyperref = true,
  extra-style=comma,
  list-style   = lof,
  list-heading = subsubsection*,
  page-style = plain,
  page-name={}
}
\printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature, sort=false]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Any ideas how to address this problem?

Comment: There is no easy solution.  `list-style   = toc` and `pages = first` is probably the best you can do. (Or another list style altogether)

Comment: Unfortunately, neither `list-style = toc`  in combination with `pages = first` nor a different list style is an option for me. Do you know if the acronym package supports these styles?

Comment: As far as I know the `acronym` package only has a list style (meaning using a LaTeX list like `description`).